# mapply of lists of matrix and vector works poorly in a specific case

Tags: r

The function `mapply()` appears not to properly work in the following case:

```
a <- list(matrix(1:8,4,2),matrix(1:9,3,3))
b <- list(1:4,1:3)
mapply(a,b,FUN=cbind)
```

that gives the following matrix

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    3    3
 [4,]    4    4
 [5,]    5    5
 [6,]    6    6
 [7,]    7    7
 [8,]    8    8
 [9,]    1    9
[10,]    2    1
[11,]    3    2
[12,]    4    3
```

instead of the following (expected) result:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    2    6    2
[3,]    3    7    3
[4,]    4    8    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7    1
[2,]    2    5    8    2
[3,]    3    6    9    3
```

Can anybody help me in understanding if something in my code is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: By default, `mapply` will try and coerce the result into an array. use the argument `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to get the expected result. It's a shame this isn't the default. I can't remember a time when I used `mapply` and didn't need to to specify `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you, using "SIMPLIFY=FALSE" it works well even though it is quite strange that if you change the number of elements into the two lists "mapply" works well without using "SIMPLIFY=FALSE"!

Comment: @MrFlick, post as answer ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set SIMPLIFY to false

```
mapply(a,b,FUN=cbind, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

otherwise `mapply` tries to coerce everything into a compatible single result. In your case, because the return from each call had 12 elements, it put those two elements side by side in a matrix, with the first matrix values in the first column, and the second matrix in the second column.

Alternatively you can use

```
Map(cbind, a, b)
```

which always returns a list. (`Map` is also nice because if `a` has names it will use those names in the resulting list which isn't useful in this case, but may be useful in others.)